# Use out of scope variable in main function

Tags: java

I have this method which uses the standard file if there are no arguments, otherwise uses the one in the argument.

```
public class MainAnimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parser parse = new Parser();
        if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0)) {
            File file = parse.getFile("findAnAnimal.csv");
        } else {
            System.out.println(args[0]);
        }
        List<String[]> animalList = parse.readFileAndParse(Paths.get(String.valueOf(file)));
```

However, `file` is getting out of scope error. I know why, because it's local to the `if` block. But what could be a workaround to this?

Comment: Do it inside the if statement.

Comment: Declare `file` outside the if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to fix this is to change this block:

```
if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0)) {
   File file = parse.getFile("findAnAnimal.csv");
} else {
   System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

into:

```
File file = null;
if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0)) {
   file = parse.getFile("findAnAnimal.csv");
} else {
   System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

keep in mind that your last line:

```
 List<String[]> animalList = parse.readFileAndParse(Paths.get(String.valueOf(file)));
```

assumes that file is not null. You should check whether file is a null beforehand or put in your existing if...else block immediately after getting file.

Comment: I meant something like this: 
if (...) {File file = getFile(); animalList = parse(file); } else ....
Keep in mind that if you do it this way you will have to declare List<String[]> animalList before this if.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the file below the if/else block.  Set a "filename" variable that defaults to 'findAnAnimal.csv' above the if block, and overrides it if there is an argument present.  This will be more robust.

```
public class MainAnimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parser parse = new Parser();
        String filename = "findAnAnimal.csv"
        if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0)) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            filename = args[0];
        }

        System.out.println("reading " + filename);
        File file = parse.getFile(filename);
        List<String[]> animalList = parse.readFileAndParse(Paths.get(String.valueOf(file)));
```